# Hide custom DIV CSS on product listings to a single product in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have resolve it.

```
 <div class="EMP-100-TAW-Craciun-Produs-I">
          <?php
          
        

    if ( get_the_ID() === 1744) { $product;
    $regular_price = esc_attr( $product->get_display_price() );
    $discount = 10;
    $currency = esc_attr( get_woocommerce_currency() );
    $new_price = $regular_price - ($regular_price * 0.10);

    echo 'Cumpără acest produs cu doar <span style="
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
">'.$new_price.$currency.'</span> prin Cadoul TAW de Crăciun';

    }


?>

</div>
```

I want in pagination, category listings to hide a custom div using PHP code,
For one particular product I want my div below title to have display: none;

I have this code but it apply to all products listings?

Any idea's? Thanks!

```
   <div class="EMP-100-TAW-Craciun-Produs-I">
          <?php

    global $product;
    $regular_price = esc_attr( $product->get_display_price() );
    $discount = 10;
    $currency = esc_attr( get_woocommerce_currency() );
    $new_price = $regular_price - ($regular_price * 0.10);

    echo 'Cumpără acest produs cu doar <span style="
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
">'.$new_price.$currency.'</span> prin Cadoul TAW de Crăciun';




?>

</div>
<?php

    if ( get_the_ID() === 1744) {
    echo "<style>.EMP-100-TAW-Craciun-Produs-I {
    display: none;
}</style>";
} 
else{
     echo "<style>.EMP-100-TAW-Craciun-Produs-I {
    display: inherit;
}</style>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

```php
<?php if(get_the_ID() == 1744) { ?>
<div class="EMP-100-TAW-Craciun-Produs-I">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

like so I would get the whole `div` only if the ID is 1744 and i need no `display: none`